# How to have plain docs mixed in with React Styleguidist

Tags: reactjs, documentation, react-styleguidist

I'd like to document other functions and parts of my code base with markdown and have them parsed and displayed in a different section of my documentation. How can I do this?

```
/**
 * Merge route into the global application state
 */ 
export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
```

Importing them directly into `styleguide.config.js` results in the entire file being parsed as text.

Answer (score 0):

[Generate Markdown](https://survivejs.com/maintenance/documentation/api/) documentation using tools like documentation.js, and then include those files [as sections](https://react-styleguidist.js.org/docs/components#sections) into Styleguidist:

```
module.exports = {
  sections: [
    {
      name: 'Some other API',
      content: 'docs/generated-file.md'
    },
    {
      name: 'Components',
      components: 'lib/components/**/*.js'
    }
  ]
}
```